# Return data from several tables in database

Tags: mysql

I need some help getting data from several tables.

This is the tables I have:

```
_______________   ______________   ___________  _______________  _____________
|_tblUsers____|   |_tblAnswers__|  |_tblAlt__|  |_tblQuestion_|  |_survey_____|
| userID      |   | answerAltID |  | altID   |  | questID     |  | surveyID   |
| username    |   | userID      |  | altText |  | questText   |  | surveyName |
|_____________|   |_____________|  |_questID_|  |_surveyID____|  |____________|
```

TblUsers have a list of users in the system, tblAnswers have all answers that has been given from users, tlbAlt holds alternatives for a question, and tblQuestion has the questions. There is one more table called tblSurveys, but that's not needed here as the ID is mentioned in the tblQuestion.

This is what I have so far:

```
SELECT
tblQuestion.questText,
tblAlt.altText,
Count(tblAnswers.answerID) as answers_count,
(SELECT COUNT(answerID) FROM tblAnswers, tblAlt 
WHERE tblAnswers.answerAltID = tblAlt.altID 
AND tblAlt.questID = " & CInt(questionID) & ") as total_count
FROM tblAlt, tblQuestion
LEFT JOIN tblAnswers ON (tblAlt.altId = tblAnswers.altID)
WHERE tblAlt.questID = " & CInt(questionID) & "
GROUP BY tblAlt.altText;
```

This returns rows like this:

> | What is blablabla? | The answer is... | 2 (has answered) | 10 (total
>   answers) |

This unfortunately only returns all rows for one question. Is there a way to get all rows that is a part of same survey (based on surveyID)?

If want the output to be like this:

> | What is blablabla? | The answer is... | 2 (has answered) | 10 (total
>   answers) | Name of Survey |

I want to return ALL alternatives (with how many answered, total answers, related question and survey).

---

**Update:**

This my input:

```
SELECT tblalternativ.altTekst, tblalternativ.altID, Count(tblsvar.svarAltID) as antSvar, 
(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tblsvar, tblalternativ 
WHERE tblsvar.svarAltID = tblalternativ.altID 
AND tblalternativ.altSpmID = " & CInt(lblQuestion.Tag) & ") as antTotal, 
(SELECT Count(*) FROM tblalternativ WHERE altSpmID = " & CInt(lblQuestion.Tag) & ") as spmTotal 
FROM(tblalternativ) LEFT JOIN tblsvar ON (tblalternativ.altId = tblsvar.svarAltID) 
WHERE(tblalternativ.altSpmID = " & CInt(lblQuestion.Tag) & ")
GROUP BY tblalternativ.altTekst ORDER BY tblalternativ.altID ASC
```

My output:

```
altTekst    altID   antSvar antTotal    spmTotal
Black         83         1      3              5
Green         84         1      3              5
Yellow        85         1      3              5
White         86         0      3              5
Pink          87         0      3              5
```

But this only show statistics for one question. I want to show for all questions in one survey. So I need to get all `altTekst` for that survey, question name, and ID of survey.

I want:

```
spmTekst      altTekst  altID   antSvar antTotal    spmTotal   evalID
What is...    Black         83         1        3          5        1
What is...    Green         84         1        3          5        1
What is...    Yellow        85         1        3          5        1
What is...    White         86         0        3          5        1
What is...    Pink          87         0        3          5        1
Who is....    The king      88         2        3          3        1
Who is....    The pope      89         0        3          3        1
Who is....    The president 90         1        3          3        1
Which....     Shoe          91         2        3          2        1
Which....     Hat           92         1        3          2        1
```

In other words, I want the statistics from all questions in same survey (based on evalID).

Comment: Oh my GOD, why dont u still show a sample output table, how desired output would look like, other than this textual description?

Comment: If you are very sure that this is the output u want, then you are wrong to say `But this only show statistics for one question.`. Actually its just a matter of selecting two additional columns with this correct query

Comment: wht are spmTekst and evalID here? which column from which table?

Comment: spmTekst is questText, and evalID is surveyID.

Comment: I know it's just about selecting two additional columns (from two tables), but it's not that easy to add into my query. :)

Comment: still we miss to see from what set of data you are querying a `SELECT`. why not show the data initially in tblquestion,tblalt and tblanswer?

Comment: and I dont think you really need evalID in your view, since that's something you are passing to query

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this(Not at all optimized, just added the survey part to it):

```
SELECT    tblQuestion.questText, tblAlt.altText, 
          Count(tblAnswers.answerAltID) AS answers_count,
           (SELECT COUNT(answerAltID) FROM tblAnswers, tblAlt 
           WHERE  tblAnswers.answerAltID = tblAlt.altID AND 
                  tblAlt.questID = " & CInt(questionID) & ") as total_count,
          survey.surveyName
FROM      survey, tblQuestion, tblAlt
LEFT JOIN tblAnswers ON (tblAlt.altId = tblAnswers.answerAltID)
WHERE     tblAlt.questID = " & CInt(questionID) & " AND 
          tblQuestion.surveyID = survey.surveyID
GROUP BY  tblAlt.altText;
```

**Edit: Try this then:**

```
SELECT    tblQuestion.questText AS spmTekst, tblAlt.altText AS altTekst, 
          tblAlt.altID, 
          Count(tblAnswers.answerAltID) AS antSvar,
          COUNT(tblAlt.altID) AS antTotal,
          COUNT(tblQuestion.questID) AS spmTotal,
          survey.surveyID AS evalID
FROM      tblQuestion 
JOIN      survey ON (survey.surveyID = tblQuestion.surveyID)
JOIN      tblAlt ON (tblAlt.questID = tblQuestion.questID)
LEFT JOIN tblAnswers ON (tblAnswers.answerAltID = tblAlt.altID)
WHERE     tblAlt.questID = " & CInt(questionID) & " AND -- what really is this? review this
          survey.surveyID = '123' -- the value u want
GROUP BY  tblAlt.altText
ORDER BY  tblAnswers.answerAltID;
```

Comment: Seems ok, but got the error `Unknown column 'tblAnswers.answerID' in 'field list'`. It's the first Count() I guess.

Comment: @user880980 realise its your own query I posted here. Just ensure the query you posted here is a valid one. Perhaps it is `tblAnswers.answerAltID` as I see in your table structure.

Comment: Yes, I fixed that. But I even get error on `Unknown column 'tblAlt.altID' in 'on clause'`.

Comment: @user880980 in that case I am helpless, do not know what is the cause. may be I could edit my answer to optimize the query which might help getting rid of that error

Comment: Works now. I swapped places for tblAlt and survey in the FROM. But this doesn't return what I really wanted. I want to return ALL alternatives (with how many answered, total answers, related question and survey). Added this info to my post.

Comment: @user880980 I just added the survey part to your query thinking you already had a working query. If that doesnt give the desired output i am helpless as to know your desired output. In that case add your input and output to your question So that I know better. Without seeing data its a tad tough :)

Comment: Ha-ha..I already tried that one before you edited it. It's pretty close now. It almost works now, but it shows the same(first) question in all `questText` columns in the output. But the rest is good.

Comment: how different then you want the output to be? after all you're providing just one questionID to fetch all this. More than any talk, just let us know the input set and output set of data u require.

Comment: Why on earth oare you using implict joins, thay are an extremely poor programming technique and were replaced 20 years ago with something better.

Comment: @HLGEM forgot to read the first line of the answer? Its called the power of Ctrl C, Ctrl V :) You are welcome to edit :)

Comment: @downvoter, my answer is only about letting the OP know how to incorporate a part missing in the original query. I stated it originally that I am not optimizing anything in the query. It is not a sin to not spare time and tweak each and every little things. And implicit joins by the way do not do any harm, after all it was mentioned in the ANSI std of 89.

Comment: They do do harm, accidental cross joins in particular. I downvote any answer using implicit joins as we should not be encouraging the use of antipatterns.

Comment: @HLGEM haha yes, but accidental again. mm I get it, you're mission is welcome :) I will surely edit my answer in a better time when I have time a bit more. I wont forget to tag u, so that u dont miss to take off the downvote :)

Comment: Have updated my post with my current query, and output. I'm pretty new to MySQL, but I will use explicit joins next time. ;)

Comment: @user880980 you haven't updated the way I asked for. Please show us a sample set of input entries of database, and then the desired output you want. **Please dont give again textual description as it can be highly misinterpreted, show the output data as in a table!**

Comment: @user880980 sorry to annoy, but where is the original set of data? That is most required.

Comment: I'm sorry, but what do you mean? The whole table structure?

Comment: No, not the whole table structure, but the existing data (the way you provided desired output) from 1 or 2 relevant tables (no need of all the tables). A couple of records will do. At least we understand it is from this set of data that u need so and so kind of results :)

Comment: This, my man, is just awsome! Works exactly the way I wanted. But I added to sort it by questionID instead, as altID doesn't necessarily ascend chronologically. Thanks a lot! Good job!

Answer (score 3):

To return all questions, answer text, count ofusers with that answer, and total answers provided; per survey.

```
Select TQ.QuestText, tAlt.altText, count(*) as Answers_count, suM(mTemp.Cnt) as total_count
FROM tblQuestion tq
LEFT JOIN tblAlt talt on Talt.QuestID = TQ.QuestID
LEFT JOIN tblAnswers ta on ta.AnswerAltID = talt.AltID
LEFT JOIN tblUsers tu ON Ta.UserID = TU.UserID
LEFT join tblAnswers ta2 on ta2.answeraltId = talt.altID
LEFT JOIN 
  (SELECT COUNT(*) cnt, questID 
   FROM tblAnswers 
   INNER JOIN tblAlt on AltID = AnswerAltID
   group by questID) mTemp 
  on mTemp.QuestID = talt.QuestID
WHERE tQ.SurveyID = 123 --Change this to your value
Group by TQ.QuestText, TAlt.AltText
```

It's just a bunch of left joins vs inner joins; and i abstracted out the counts for each table once so it should be faster instead of doing a sub select on each row.  This way it does it once for all rows and is done.

Comment: I'm getting "unknown column questID" after last `LEFT JOIN`.

Comment: I corrected nTemp to mTemp.  I also added sum(mtemp.cnt) at top.

Comment: Yes, I tried it after you edited. Unfortunately it gave me the error.

Comment: hmm... maybe a group by is needed on the inner join... didn't think it was needed in mysql though...  Note I can't test this as I don't have access to mysql presently.

Comment: Already tried that, and several other things. It surely gets too complex for me now.

Comment: Well maybe someone else can step in becuase that looks right to me no mySQL availalbe for me to test this. :(